# operator overloading seeking concept

Tags: c++

```
class A{
..........
..........
};

int x;
A a;

x=a + x;  // option 1
x=x + a;  // option 2
x+=a; // option 3
```

Will the operator + overload for all option 1 2, & 3 will be same? i.e. 
int A::operator+(int s)

if not why and what for others?

Comment: Ahh, let me update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

This will call `A::operator +(int)`, or `operator +(A, int)`:

```
x=a + x;  // option 1
```

This will call `operator +(int, A)` (there's no such thing as `int::operator +(A)`):

```
x=x + a;  // option 2
```

This will call `operator +=(int, A)` (but you had better make the first argument `A&`, not just `A` or you won't actually be able to write a working `+=` operator). There's no such thing as `int::operator +=(A)`:

```
x+=a; // option 3
```

The reason they call different operator overloads is because they are different... not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: Should I pass A by ref? I mean operator +(int, &A)

Comment: @RoshanMehta for operator + it can be `const A&` if you want to avoid a copy, otherwise `A` is fine. But for the left side of `operator +=` it has to be `A&` so you can change the value.

Comment: Will `x+=a;` call `operator +=(A, int)`?IMO `a+=x` will call `operator +=(A, int)`.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Yep, I got it backwards. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

No operator overloading needed at *all*, since you basically do `int + int` or `int += int`.

However, for completeness, for an operation such as `A + B` the overload resolution is

1. `A.operator+(B)`
2. `operator+(A, B)`

For `+=` it's different since it's a separate operator, `operator+=`. It can't have any non-member overload (no assignment operator can), so for `A += B` the only possible attempt is `A.operator+=(B)`.

---

After your edit, option 1 is still `A.operator(x)` or `operator+(A, x)` (as outlined above).

Option 2 can't have a member overload, so the only viable variant is `opetrator+(x, A)`, or `x + static_cast<int>(A)`.

Option 3 can only be `x += static_cast<int>(A)`.

The `static_cast<int>(A)` option will use an `operator int` overload. If that doesn't exist then those alternatives are not possible and you will get an error when building.

---

I also recommend e.g. [this operator overloading reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). And of course that you read [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: just updated my question, after your comment which you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

In your example,if you do like `A::operator+(int s)`,then this overloading does not work for `x+a`,unless you define a type conversion like `operator int()`. Because the `operator +` as member function will has the implicit `this` pointer as the `rhs` parameter.

So it's recommended for you to **overload the `operator +` as non-member function**.And if necessary,provide a implicit type conversion like`operator int()`,or `A(int)`;

Once you decide to overload `operator+`,it's recommend to provide `operator+=` as well,so as `*,/,-` . Because the compiler will not generate the `operator+=` automaticlly for you.